# Rpgle Double byte issue

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Have an issue with the following bit of code:-

```
C                   eval      aaCHNO=%ucs2('0000000000')        
C**                 move      w_Chano       aaCHNO              
C                   Evalr     aaCHNO= %ucs2(%editc(w_Chano:'X'))
```

Definitions :

```
AACHNO            Char(10) CCSID(1200)  
W_CHANO           Packed(6,0)
```

In AACHNO was expecting :- 0000123456 but get 'bbbb123456' where b=blank why?

How do I get the results I want?
cheers,
Jemrug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The op-code `EVALR` does not work like `MOVE`, it works like `MOVE(P)`. In order to get the behavior you want, you are going to have to use `%SUBST()` or concatenate `'0's` to the front of your value like this:

```
C                   Evalr     aaCHNO = %ucs2('0000000000') + %ucs2(%editc(w_Chano:'X'))
```

or in free format use:

```
evalr aaCHNO = %ucs2('0000000000') + %ucs2(%editc(w_Chano:'X'));
```

**Note:** There are a couple constructs that you do not actually attach a type to, so they are defined as `char()`. Character constants are one of them. Another is data structures. When you are using `UCS2` data, you must remember this and convert the constants, and only use fields or sub-fields explicitly defined as `UCS2`. Otherwise conversion will take place.

Comment: Mark, I think you need EVALR for the free-form version too.